# How to register open generic with custom factory method?

Tags: c#, autofac

**TL;DR**: Can I create a generic factory with Autofac, so that I can inject `IProduct<TModel>` rather than resolving it from `IFactory` anywhere I need it? Is there a way to move the resolving-from-factory task to the composition root?

So I'm using a third party library, which exposes some generic interfaces which are created through a factory. For demonstration purposes, we'll assume that the following code is the library:

**Third party library mock-up**:

```
public interface IFactory
{
    IProduct<TModel> CreateProduct<TModel>(string identifier);
}

internal class Factory : IFactory
{
    private readonly string _privateData = "somevalues";

    public IProduct<TModel> CreateProduct<TModel>(string identifier)
    {
        return new Product<TModel>(_privateData, identifier);
    }
}

public interface IProduct<TModel>
{
    void DoSomething();
}

internal sealed class Product<TModel>: IProduct<TModel>
{
    private readonly string _privateData;
    private readonly string _identifier;

    public Product(string privateData, string identifier)
    {
        _privateData = privateData;
        _identifier = identifier;
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"{_privateData} + {_identifier}");
    }
}
```

**My code**:

And my `TModel`:

```
public class Shoe { }
```

Now, let's assume that I want an `IProduct<Shoe>` in `MyService`. I need to resolve it there:

```
public class MyService
{
    public MyService(IFactory factory)
    {
        IProduct<Shoe> shoeProduct = factory.CreateProduct<Shoe>("theshoe");
    }
}
```

But wouldn't it be nicer if I could declare shoe like this:

```
public class ProductIdentifierAttribute : System.Attribute
{
    public string Identifier { get; }

    public ProductIdentifierAttribute(string identifier)
    {
        this.Identifier = identifier;
    }
}

[ProductIdentifier("theshoe")]
public class Shoe { }
```

and then inject it like this?:

```
public class MyService
{
    public MyService(IProduct<Shoe> shoeProduct) { }
}
```

With Autofac I can use a factory to create regular non-generic classes like so:

```
builder
    .Register<INonGenericProduct>(context =>
    {
        var factory = context.Resolve<INonGenericFactory>();
        return factory.CreateProduct("bob");
    })
    .AsImplementedInterfaces();
```

But this doesn't work for generic classes. I have to use `RegisterGeneric`. Unfortunately, the type you pass to `RegisterGeneric` is the open *concrete* type, rather than the open *interface* type. I've come up with two workarounds.

**Workaround 1**: Reflect `IFactory` to extract `_privateData` (in the real library this is somewhat more complicated, and involves accessing other `internal` methods and classes, etc.) and then supply that as Autofac parameters in `OnPreparing`:

```
Type factoryType = typeof(Factory);
Type factoryField = factoryType.GetField("_privateData", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Getfield);
Type productType = typeof(Product); // this is `internal` in the third party library, so I have to look it up from the assembly in reality

builder
.RegisterGeneric(productType)
.OnPreparing(preparing =>
{
    var factory = preparing.Context.Resolve<IFactory>();
    var privateFieldValue = factoryField.GetValue(factory);
    var closedProductType = preparing.Component.Activator.LimitType;
    var productModel = closedProductType.GetGenericArguments().Single();
    var productIdentifier = productModel.GetGenericArgument<ProductIdentifierAttribute>().Identifier;

    preparing.Parameters = new List<Parameter>()
    {
        new PositionalParameter(0, privateFieldValue),
        new PositionalParameter(0, productIdentifier)
    };
})
.AsImplementedInterfaces();
```

But clearly this is a **terrible solution** for numerous reasons, the most significant being that it's vulnerable to internal changes within the library.

**Workaround 2**: Create a dummy type and substitute it in `OnActivating`:

```
public class DummyProduct<TModel> : IProduct<TModel>
{
    public void DoSomething() => throw new NotImplementedException("");
}
```

So, we register that as the open generic, and substitute its value before injecting it:

```
MethodInfo openProductBuilder = this.GetType().GetMethod(nameof(CreateProduct), BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod);
builder
    .RegisterGeneric(typeof(DummyProduct<>))
    .OnActivating(activating => 
    {
        var productModel = activating.Instance.GetType().GetGenericArguments().First();
        var productIdentifier = productModel.GetGenericArgument<ProductIdentifierAttribute>().Identifier;
        var factory = activating.Context.Resolve<IFactory>();
        var closedProductBuilder = openProductBuilder.MakeGenericMethod(productModel);
        object productObject = closedProductBuilder.Invoke(this, new object[] { factory, productIdentifier });
        handler.ReplaceInstance(productObject);
    })
    .AsImplementedInterfaces();
```

and we have a helper method so that we're only reliant on reflecting methods *in this Mongo module class*:

```
private IProduct<TModel> CreateProduct<TModel>(IFactory factory, string identifier)
{
    return factory.CreateProduct<TModel>(identifier);
}
```

Now, clearly this is better than the first method, and doesn't rely on too much reflection. Unfortunately, it does involve creating a dummy object each time we want the real one. That sucks!

**Question**: Is there another way to do this using Autofac? Can I somehow create a generic factory method that Autofac can use? My main goal is to cut out the creating the dummy type, and skip straight to calling the `CreateProduct` code.

**Notes**: I've cut out a fair bit of error checking, etc. that I would normally do to make this question as short as possible whilst still adequately demonstrating the problem and my current solutions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there is no non generic `Create` method in your factory you will need a call to the `MakeGenericMethod`.

Instead of `OnActivating` event you can use a `IRegistrationSource` component that will do the same as in your workaround 2

```
internal class FactoryRegistrationSource : IRegistrationSource
{
    private static MethodInfo openProductBuilder = typeof(Factory).GetMethod(nameof(Factory.CreateProduct));

    public Boolean IsAdapterForIndividualComponents => false;

    public IEnumerable<IComponentRegistration> RegistrationsFor(Service service, Func<Service, IEnumerable<IComponentRegistration>> registrationAccessor)
    {
        IServiceWithType typedService = service as IServiceWithType;

        if (typedService != null && typedService.ServiceType.IsClosedTypeOf(typeof(IProduct<>)))
        {
            IComponentRegistration registration = RegistrationBuilder.ForDelegate(typedService.ServiceType, (c, p) =>
             {
                 IFactory factory = c.Resolve<IFactory>();

                 Type productModel = typedService.ServiceType.GetGenericArguments().First();
                 String productIdentifier = productModel.GetCustomAttribute<ProductIdentifierAttribute>()?.Identifier;

                 MethodInfo closedProductBuilder = openProductBuilder.MakeGenericMethod(productModel);
                 Object productObject = closedProductBuilder.Invoke(factory, new object[] { productIdentifier });

                 return productObject;
             }).As(service).CreateRegistration();
            yield return registration;
        }
        yield break;
    }
}
```