# Register ImmutableArray with autofac

Tags: c#, autofac, ioc-container

Autofac allows you to register generic types with the RegisterGeneric method.

I would like to register `ImmutableArray<T>`.

The semantics I want are the same as for `IEnumerable<T>` - namely `Autofac` should create an instance of an `ImmutableArray<T>` with all registrations of `T`.

If this was non generic it would be simple:

```cs
builder.Register<ImmutableArray<string>>(c => c.Resolve<IEnumerable<string>>().ToImmutableArray());
```

However I can't see any way to that with generic types.

Comment: I don't have an answer to your exact question, but you may end up with something like I got in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57290563) that I asked a while ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no easy way to register a generic method with a lambda expression. You need to use a `IRegistrationSource` with generic type manipulation to do that.

Something like that :

```
public class ImmutableArrayRegistrationSource : IRegistrationSource
{
    public bool IsAdapterForIndividualComponents => false;

    private static MethodInfo toImmutableArrayMethod =
            typeof(ImmutableArray)
                .GetMethods()
                .Where(m => m.Name == nameof(ImmutableArray.ToImmutableArray)
                            && m.GetParameters().Any(p => p.ParameterType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEnumerable<>)))
                .FirstOrDefault();

    public IEnumerable<IComponentRegistration> RegistrationsFor(Service service, Func<Service, IEnumerable<IComponentRegistration>> registrationAccessor)
    {
        IServiceWithType typedService = service as IServiceWithType;

        if (typedService != null && typedService.ServiceType.IsClosedTypeOf(typeof(ImmutableArray<>)))
        {
            Type elementType = typedService.ServiceType.GetGenericArguments()[0];

            IComponentRegistration r = RegistrationBuilder.ForDelegate(typedService.ServiceType, (c, p) =>
            {
                Object elements = c.Resolve(typeof(IEnumerable<>).MakeGenericType(elementType));
                Object immutableArray = toImmutableArrayMethod.MakeGenericMethod(elementType)
                                                              .Invoke(null, new Object[] { elements });

                return immutableArray;
            }).As(service)
              .CreateRegistration();

            yield return r;
        }
        yield break;
    }
}
```

and then register your registration source :

```
builder.RegisterSource<ImmutableArrayRegistrationSource>();
```